# Why is the onClick method of the recyclerview not working

Tags: android

I have a recylerview and everything is working. The problem is when i click an item of the recyclerview it toasts the message "It is working" but does not go to a new fragment. I cannot solve this problem for a week and could not see a way out other than asking. Thank you for the help.

SearchFragment.java

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(CartModel cartModel) {

        ItemClickedFragment itemClickedFragment = new ItemClickedFragment();
        SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .hide(searchFragment)
                .replace(R.id.SearchFragment,itemClickedFragment)
                .setReorderingAllowed(false)
                .commit();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "It is working!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

CartAdapter.java

```
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<CartModel> cartModelList;
    private Context context;
    private SelectListener listener;

    public CartAdapter(List<CartModel> cartModelList, Context context, SelectListener listener) {
        this.cartModelList = cartModelList;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.shopping_cart_items,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CartModel cartModel = cartModelList.get(position);

        //Set the data to positions
        holder.name.setText(cartModel.getName());
        holder.uni.setText(cartModel.getUni());
        holder.course.setText(cartModel.getCourse());
        holder.page.setText(cartModel.getPage());
        holder.price.setText(cartModel.getPrice());

        //Load the images into the cardviews
        Picasso.get().load(cartModel.getImage()).into(holder.image);

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onItemClicked(cartModelList.get(position));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cartModelList.size();
    }
    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    public void setFilteredList(List<CartModel> filteredList){
        this.cartModelList = filteredList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView image;
        TextView name;
        TextView uni;
        TextView course;
        TextView page;
        TextView price;
        public CardView cardView;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            //Get the shopping_cart_items views
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartImage);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartName);
            uni = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartUni);
            course = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartCourse);
            page = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartPage);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartPrice);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerItems);

        }
    }
}
```

SelectListener.java (Adapter interface)

```
public interface SelectListener {
    void onItemClicked(CartModel cartModel);
}
```

fragment_search.xml (Recyclerview is here)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".SearchFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/SearchFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/SearchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:queryHint="Not arayın"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/SearchRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

shopping_cart_items.xml (Here is single cardview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Your CardView layout -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cartImage"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="115dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop">
            </ImageView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cartName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000">
                </TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cartUni"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000">
                </TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cartCourse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp">
                </TextView>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cartPage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#000000">
                    </TextView>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cartPrice"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#000000">
                    </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When items of the recyclerview is onclicked, the fragment does not change as it should.

Comment: What does the XML with R.id.SearchFragment look like? Also you are creating new instance of SearchFragment and trying to hide that - I think you should use "this" - .hide(this)

Answer (score 0):

at first `View` with `id` `SearchFragment` is a `LinearLayout`, which has two childs fulfilling it (as `RecyclerView`s `layout_height="match_parent"`), so your fragments are probably there, but below RV and without possibility of scrolling whole layout...

but you are doing this very wrong, you very shouldn't replace layout of some `Fragment` with yet another (nested) `Fragment`. if you VERY want/need to do this, you should use `childFragmentManager` at least, but you probably should close/remove `SearchFragment` and place new `ItemClickedFragment` in container, which was used by SF. or on top of it for keeping search results in backstack (then container should be `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`)

Comment: I will try to figutre out the solutions and get back to you. Thanks for the help !!